USB Communication between Ardunino Android
I'm trying to develop an android application that communicates with arduino via USB. I've already implement the class that allows me to connect both devices.
On Android side i have the following code to establish the connection:
    public boolean openUsbConnection(UsbDevice usbDevice,int baudRate){
    _isConnected = false;
    if(connection != null) {
        _isConnected = true;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice,permissionIntent);
        if(usbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice)){
            connection = usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice);
            if(connection!=null){
                //int res1 = connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
                // res2 = connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0, 0, getLineEncoding(baudRate), 7, 0);
                //if(setTransferParameters(CDC_SET_LINE_CODING,0,getLineEncoding(baudRate)) >=0
                        //&& setTransferParameters(CDC_SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE,CDC_CONTROL_LINE_ON,null)>=0){
                    if(getInOutEndPoint(usbDevice)){
                    _isConnected = true;
                    }
                //}

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

in the above function, connection.controlTransfer is disabled because it always returns -1 and I saw that without it I can still connect the devices.
In order to read/write data I used the following functions:
 public int sendData(byte[] data, int timeout){
    if(_isConnected){
    Log.d("USB_DEBUG", "usbOutEndPoint: " + usbOutEndPoint);
    Log.d("USB_DEBUG", "connection: " + connection);
    int length = 0;
    if(data!=null)length= data.length;
   return connection.bulkTransfer(usbOutEndPoint, data, length, timeout);
    }
    else return -2;
}
public int readData(byte[] buffer, int timeout) {
    if (_isConnected) {
        try {
            Log.d("USB_DEBUG", "usbOutEndPoint: " + usbOutEndPoint);
            Log.d("USB_DEBUG", "connection: " + connection);

            int bytesRead = connection.bulkTransfer(usbInEndPoint, buffer, buffer.length, timeout);

            if (bytesRead < 0) {
                Log.e("USB_DEBUG", "Error occurred during bulk transfer. bytesRead: " + bytesRead);
            }

            return bytesRead;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("USB_DEBUG", "Exception occurred during bulk transfer: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            return -1; // Return -1 to indicate an error occurred
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("USB_DEBUG", "USB is not connected.");
        return -2; // Return -2 if USB is not connected
    }
}

To send data from android finally I did this:
    void BtnOnClick(View view) {
    if(view == startBtn)
    {
        int result = arduinoManager.sendData(new byte[]{1},5000);
        int result2 = arduinoManager.readData(new byte[1],5000);
    }
    else if(view == btn)
    {
        int result = arduinoManager.sendData(new byte[]{0},5000);
        int result2 = arduinoManager.readData(new byte[1],5000);
    }
}

In order to check if there's communication between android and arduino I did on the arduino side the following:
    void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        if(ledState == 1) ledState == 0;
        else ledState = 1;}
    Serial.write(ledState);
}

when I sent data from android, the led in the arduino turned on, so i'm sure both devices are communicating, also in the result of the reading function I got a value of "1".
The problem is when I try to turn on the led when pressing a button in the android and turn the led off when pressing another button, from android side I dont get any errors and it says that 1 byte was sent.
On the arduino side the led doesn't turn on. Unfortunately I cannot use the serial monitor because it is being used by the android device. The function I used in arduino was:
    int led = 13;
bool ledState = LOW;

void setup() {
    // Initialize the LED pin as an output
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // Check if data is available to read from serial
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        byte received = Serial.read();

        // Update the LED state based on the received value
        if (received == 1) {
            ledState = HIGH; // Turn the LED on
        } else if (received == 0) {
            ledState = LOW; // Turn the LED off
        }

        Serial.write(ledState); 
    }

    // Update the LED with the current state
    digitalWrite(led, ledState);
}

but I cannot find a way to do the led to turn on. I even asked chatgpt what can I do but it just confused me a lot because its answers were contradictory. ;(
What can I do to make it works?

Is it sending a raw 1 or ascii '1' (aka 49)?

I tried this but it still doesn't work
byte received = Serial.read(); if (received == 49) {ledState = HIGH; } else if (received== 48) {ledState = LOW; }

It's difficult to implement your own library, I used this library instead and now it works perfectly
